# What should happen when non-purchased user press the restore purchase button in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My sandbox test account can purchase non-consumable item and restore it. Everything works. However, if the account have not purchased the item before, pressing the restore button does nothing. I see nothing in the debug panel. I'm expecting iOS to detect if a certain user has purchased the item or not, if not then display a message asking them to buy it. Does it work like that or the current behavior is totally acceptable?

Here is the restore purchase code (Swift) connecting to a button inside the main storyboard:

```
@IBAction func restoreButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    statusLabel.text = "Status: Restoring Purchase"
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

Other implemented methods include:

Works for normal purchase

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {}
```

Works for normal restore

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {}
```

Never see messages coming from this method before

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError!) {}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if the queue has any returned transactions, and if not it means that there are no purchases to restore:

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
  if queue.transactions.count == 0 {
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Oops"
    alert.message = "There are no purchases to restore, please buy one"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Buy")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    alert.show()
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I haven't thought about checking the number of transactions!

Comment: Thank you!  My app got rejected because my Restore button was doing nothing when users hadn't purchased my IAP.  The rejection reason was unclear, but I think that this will take care of it.

Comment: Hi, in my app I've used the same if statement to check queue.transactions amount, but it gives me 1 even if i never purchased the product, don't know why, so what my app performs is a restore anyway, which means that users get the IAP for free if they tap my Restore Purchase button. That happens in Sandbox mode and also when the app is live on the App Store. iOS 10, Swift 3. Is it an Apple bug?

Comment: if transactions.count > 0 then can I call receipt validation function ?

Comment: Hi, I am getting reciept by apple and it gives me 1 day subscription for that product when I click on restore btn without purchase that product.

Comment: I have the same problem of @xscoder , any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {


    for transaction in transactions {

        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing: print("Payment is being processed")

        case .purchased: print("USER PURCHASED YOUR PRODUCT")

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

        case .restored:

            if transaction.original?.transactionIdentifier != nil { // this identifier uniquely identifies a completed tansaction.
        //    queue.restoreCompletedTransactions()

                print("THE BUYER BOUGHT THIS PRODUCT BEFORE")

            } else {
             /*
              display UIAlertController showing an error
              there is no receipts, user never purchased this product.
                                */
            }


        case .failed:
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .deferred:

           print("pending")

        @unknown default:
           break
        }


    }


}
```